# Unable to install laravel through composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, command-prompt

I have got many solution for this but still cant resolve this issue.
When I run the following command:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

I got this error:

```
Changed current directory to C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Installing symfony/console (v2.6.1)
Downloading: 100%
Downloading: 100%
Downloading: 100%
Failed to download symfony/console from dist: The "https://api.github.com/re
pos/symfony/Console/zipball/ef825fd9f809d275926547c9e57cbf14968793e8" file could
not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host i
s known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such hos
t is known.
Now trying to download from source
- Installing symfony/console (v2.6.1)
Cloning ef825fd9f809d275926547c9e57cbf14968793e8



[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone git@github.com:symfony/Console.git, git was not found, chec
k that it is installed and in your PATH env.
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.



require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update]
[--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-
packages] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Am I doing some mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was DNS -

I used Google DNS instead of mine internet service provider.

And this trick solves the issue.

Comment: Its because we are using MTNL ISP for internet connection and recently they have blocked github.com.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clearly shown in the output thrown.

```
[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone git@github.com:symfony/Console.git, git was not found, chec
k that it is installed and in your PATH env.
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

You don't have git installed. Install git on your system and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the problem was different. Please see my answer.